# VPNый dns не резолвит внешние адреса, внешний не резолвит VPNые

Tags: macos, dns, vpn

Есть vpn корпоративный который при подключении на моем mac os x BigSure, в настройках подключения к сети меняет dns c локального DNS моего роутера на внутрекорпоративные.
Внутренние сервисы начинают резолвится а внешние нет.

Пробовал дописать DNS сервер 8.8.8.8 в настройках сети к тем что есть, если поставить в после тех vpn овских dns серверов то так же, внешние не резолвятся.
Если поставить перед vpn овскими серверами внешний, то внешние начинают резолвится, а внутренние перестают.

Предполагаю что их можно как-то объединить, чтоб если vpn овский dns сервер не отдал запись то резолвить запись через dns сервер роутера или восьмерки.

Но не знаю как это на маке сделать.

Comment: Подозреваю, что для маршрутизации только части трафика надо устанавливать приложение, а не настраивать vpn в системе.

Comment: собственный микроскопический nameserver запустите. например: [dnsmasq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29004054/4827341)

Answer (score 0):

Установка dnsmasq и настройка нужных nameservers решили проблему. Вот по этой статье
https://gist.github.com/ogrrd/5831371

Установил dnsmask.
И в файле конфигурации dnsmasq dnsmasq.conf указал в директиве server=name_iskomogo.dns/ip_dns_servera_kotoriy_dolghen_resolvit_daniy_domen
Спасибо aleksandr barakin!

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/696493)

Comment: P.S. может ответ и корректный, но сходу не понятно, что конкретно вы сделали кроме установки dnsmasq

Comment: @insolor, вероятно, воспользовался опцией `server` у dnsmasq-а.